# Use Local Storage in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, local-storage

The following code works fine in Chrome.  But in IE11, Developer Tools give me this:

```
Unable to get property 'clickcount' of undefined or null reference.
```

Here is the code:

```
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount=Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        }
        else  {
            localStorage.clickcount=1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
```

It's right out of the W3schools web page on HTML5 Web Storage.

What to do?

Comment: Don't set properties of `localStorage`; use the provided methods: `getItem()` and `setItem()` (just saying)

Comment: Also, I don't see the error happening in IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/M92Fw/

Comment: same for me I get no error in IE 11